# Does Azure Purview have Federated Data Catalogue capability?

Tags: azure-purview, azure-data-catalog

I am exploring options to create a data mesh using Azure native services and need a Federated Data Catalogue.Could the following be accomplished:

- Create the Azure Data Platform 1 with Purview Data Catalogue 1 cataloging the related data assets
- Create the Azure Data Platform 2 with Purview Data Catalogue 2 cataloging the related data assets
- Create a Federated Azure Purview Data Catalogue 3 where Purview Data Catalogue 1 & 2 synchs its contents automatically to Purview Data Catalogue 3.
- Allow users to search all the company assets from Purview Data Catalogue 3 and request access to the data from Azure Data Platform 1 or Azure Data Platform 2 to consume the data.

Thanks
CK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is not a built-in feature currently for Azure Purview.
- The recommended approach would be to use [Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-create-and-manage-collections) and the [Data Access Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-access-policies-storage) to support the access control.
- If you must support scanning via one Purview instance and copying to another, you may subscribe to data catalog events using the [Purview Kafka Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/manage-kafka-dotnet) and then use some compute to relay them to the other catalog.
- You should also consider doing a [one-time Purview migration](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas/tree/master/samples/migratePurview) if Purview Data Catalog 1 and 2 already have scanned assets.